# Прервать цикл при совпадении

Tags: javascript

Как прервать цикл при нахождении совпадения? Функция перекликивает табы на странице. Должна остановиться на табе, локатор которого я передал в nameOfTab.

```
goOnTab: function(nameOfTab){
      for (let nameOfTab in locators.tabs){
        if (nameOfTab === locators.tabs)
        break;
        this.click(locators.tabs[nameOfTab])
      }
```

Мое условие игнорируется и цикл проходит по всем табам.

Структура хранения локаторов:

```
const locators = {
  tabs: {
      home: 'Товары для дома',
      girl: 'Женская одежда и аксессуары',
      bag: 'Чемоданы и сумки',
      sport: 'Хобби, спорт, путешествия',
      children: 'Детские товары',
  }}
```

Comment: а вы пробовали в каждом проходе смотреть, что хранит  в себе  nameOfTab и locators.Tab? Посмотрите действиетльно ли есть совпания. Возможно что проблема в том что вам нужно дополнить условие. Перед циклом вставьте вывод обеих переменных в консоль например и посмотреите после того как программа отработает есть ли строка в которой вывелось 2 одинаковых значения. И вообще что выводится в том и другом случае

Comment: `locators.tabs` разве не перечисление?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру дополнил вопрос. Это место хранения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
function(last) {
    for (let nameOfTab in locators.tabs) {
        if (nameOfTab === last) {
            break;
        } 
        this.click(locators.tabs[nameOfTab])
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @ВадимАлександру теперь останавливается, но на один таб раньше, чем переданный

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin стараюсь как могу